# string from array to array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project for school. We have to read a file of multiple lines of comma separated info(multiple pieces of info per line) and create a new array with just one piece of the data. So far I have created an array where each element contains a list of each piece of data. What I need help with is how to take that list and make it into a new array. Here is the code I have to create the first array. The header String that I have is just to read past the first line of the text file that I am reading from. I use the scanner to read the file, and then the lastNamesArray has elements that contain all the info from the file, each element has all the info from the corresponding spot in the source file. I need to get the list from lastNamesArray[1] into the new array.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(rosterFile);
    String header = input.nextLine();
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String lastNames = input.nextLine();    
        String[] lastNamesArray = lastNames.split(",");
```

Comment: And why is it a problem for you?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `ArrayList` (not array) as your result?

Comment: I'm confused. You want the first element of `lastNamesArray` added to this new `Array`? Or each element added to the `Array`?

Comment: as your variables are defined within the `loop` there will only be visible within the loop **and** also they will get overridden on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: PM 77-1. I'm not sure, I missed a few days of lecture going over arrays, so I may have missed that lesson.

Comment: GBlodgett, correct, the first element in lastNamesArray is actually multiple names, and I need those in a new array